# Strange SOQL Query result

Tags: soql

So i used two queries one after another in same org:

Q1:

```
SELECT Id,Name, Project__c, Activity__c, AMS_Solutions_c__c
FROM Design_Time_Sheet__c
WHERE Project__c = null OR Activity__c = null
ORDER BY AMS_Solutions_c__c
```

Q2:

```
SELECT Id,Name, Project__c, Activity__c, AMS_Solutions_c__c
FROM Design_Time_Sheet__c
WHERE Project__c = null AND Activity__c = null
ORDER BY AMS_Solutions_c__c
```

What is strange is result of both. When used one with AND it returns 0 rows but when I use the other one I get this:

[image]

All of the records have the two lookup fields I add in the WHERE statement emoty. So why putting AND there cause it to throw 0 rows?

Both of these are look up fields.

Comment: Is `Project__c` or `Activity__c` required lookup field?

Comment: Arulkumar it will but the question is still open. I faced a similar problem with determining a field value as NULL or blank ''. We still need clarification by Top StackExchange contributors.

Comment: Try this clause in your query 2: 
`WHERE (Project__c = null OR Project__c = '') AND (Activity__c = null OR Activity__c = '')`
does it return results?

Comment: It might help to see the query plan for both queries (Help => Preferences => check the "Enable Query Plan" box to get the "Query Plan" button in the query editor tab of the Dev Console)